# mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax when trying to create a table

Tags: python, mysql, sql

> mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Rank int, XP int, PRIMARY KEY (UUID))' at line 1

the code is using mysql.connector in python 3.9

```
c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS UserActivity(UUID int, TotalMessages int, Rank int, XP int, PRIMARY KEY (UUID))')
```

Answer (score 1):

The word Rank is a reserved keyword, had to replace all instances of Rank with UR

```
c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS UserActivity(UUID int, TotalMessages int, UR int, XP int, PRIMARY KEY (UUID))')
```

Comment: Link tip: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_reserved_words, RANK is reserved by SQL-2016, MySQL and Teradata.